# Word characters without decimal characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate an input, and the easiest way I have at the moment is through a single regexp.

I want to check on all characters that could be in a name, so special characters like ü should be allowed, like in Schüssler. But digits shouldn't be allowed, otherwise I would have just used \w.

So I tried to match on all word characters excluding the digits and _, but I can't get this to work. 
So can someone show me how to make this work (if it's possible), or give me another solution that doesn't involve mentioning all possible special characters that are allowed?

Comment: What special characters are allowed? You with a reverse range (specifying characters that are not allowed), but that is presumably even a harder task because it will allow all kind of symbols and other junk that cannot be parts of names.

Comment: If you're using a regex, it's probably easiest to just specify the list of valid characters.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/screens/rxbcharclass.png

The western europe variant without the decimals and _ basically

Comment: Yeah, internationalization support for regex is a contradiction of terms. You'll just have to manually list them all.

Comment: And the other option is to use 2 regexp-statements, and check if it matches word characters and doesn't match decimals and other stuff. Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will match/allow everything but the things within the `[^]`.

```
/[^_0-9 ]+/g
```

Comment: That would work, but then I'd have to include all thing I don't want, which is shorter but still a decent list.

Comment: @Johan Well you won't get around this. Somewhere and -how you have to specify what you want and what you don't, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This will catch most of the accents for romance languages. If you need more, add them:

```
/^[a-záéíóäëiöúàèììù]+$/i
```

Comment: The OP also wanted to match umlauts and accented characters, which don't have a nice `ä-ÿ` range.

Answer (score -1):

Why not do the opposite and check *only* for the things you don't want:

```
if (!name.match(/[0-9_]/g)) {
  // Name has no underscores or digits. Keep validating
} else {
  // Ask the user why they have digits in their name
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, show yourself. An explanation of why my answer is invalid would be nice.